# gspread - Import header titles and start data on Row 2

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, gspread

I run a daily script checking 50 prices via Beautiful Soup and gspread.

I clear the data using clear() but the script also clears the header title (Column 1 etc) and then starts the data import on the next row after the rows I have cleared. (Row 51)

**How can I insert some headers and start the data import from cell A2?**

I have tried the following code, but no joy yet

```
worksheet = wks.worksheet('automated')
worksheet.clear()
worksheet.insert_row(Column A, Column B)
first_row = worksheet.('A2')
first_col = worksheet.('A2')
```

[image]

Comment: post the url...

Comment: Here is an example of the Google Sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/125V-EMpp2yLWDRIiOaL0JsZ5-48yZ0w9FDLkRhNuiyk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can use insert_row with the index parameter as 1 for the header:

```
header = ["header_col1","header_col2"]
index = 1
sheet.insert_row(header, index)
```

Then use a loop to insert at the second row each data import:

```
for row in rows_to_import:
    row = ["data_import_col1","data_import_col2"]
    index = 2
    sheet.insert_row(row, index)
```

You can find the docs for insert_row [here](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Worksheet.insert_row).

Comment: Code-only answers are low-quality answers. Add some detail; explain why this is this code snippet works.